# Client and server script issues roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I am having this problem when trying to insert an event in my game and I don't know how to solve it exactly, could someone help me to know how to solve it..

**client script:**

```
-- Events
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Evento = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent
-- end of Events
local button = script.Parent
local frame = script.Parent.Parent.Frame

Evento.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(argumento1)
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if frame.Visible == false then
    frame.Visible = true
    button.Text = "Cerrar"
    button.Visible = false  
    else
    frame.Visible = false
    print("El frame esta invisible.")       
    end
    end)
end)
```

**ServerScript**

```
-- Events
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Evento = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent
-- end of Events

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    Evento:FireClient(player,"argumento1")
end)
```

**Output error:**
  11:36:52.328  ReadyButton is not a valid member of ScreenGui "Players.MatiasHarders.PlayerGui.TeamChangerGui"  -  Server  -  Script:19

**Explorer image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlX7E.png)

Comment: Please provide information on where the "ReadyButton" comes from. Your code doesn't include a single reference to it.

Comment: At the end attach a picture called as "Explorer image" do you think you could help me please

Comment: The image doesn't help me, sorry. But are the sections of code you provided the full scripts or just parts of them

Comment: Please provide the code from where the error is thrown.